# Filter out a particular category

Tags: r, filter, dplyr

Here's a sample dataset.

```
a <- structure(list(ID = c("A1", "A2", "A3", "A1", "A1", "A2", "A4", "A5", "A2", "A3"), 
Type = c("A", "B", "C", "A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "C", "B"), 
Alc = c("E", "F", "G", "E", "E", "E", "F", "F", "F", "F"), 
Com = c("Y", "N", "Y", "N", "Y", "Y", "Y", "N", "N", "Y")),
.Names = c("ID", "Type", "Alc", "Com"), row.names = c(NA, -10L), class = "data.frame")
a
   ID Type Alc Com
1  A1    A   E   Y
2  A2    B   F   N
3  A3    C   G   Y
4  A1    A   E   N
5  A1    A   E   Y
6  A2    A   E   Y
7  A4    B   F   Y
8  A5    B   F   N
9  A2    C   F   N
10 A3    B   F   Y
```

I want to get a dataset having no "E" in Alc. I do the following.

```
library(dplyr)
b <- filter(a, Alc=="G"| Alc=="F")
b
  ID Type Alc Com
1 A2    B   F   N
2 A3    C   G   Y
3 A4    B   F   Y
4 A5    B   F   N
5 A2    C   F   N
6 A3    B   F   Y
```

If there are lots of categories in Alc, it's troublesome to write down all categories. I need an easy fix.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the "not equal" operator `!=`

```
b <- filter(a, Alc!="E")
```

Comment: I tried to do it; don't have any idea what happened then. Now it works.

Comment: Note that `%in%` can also be helpful in situations like this (e.g. `Alc %in% c("G","F")` or `!(Alc %in% c("E"))`

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
a[a$Alc!='E',]
   ID Type Alc Com
2  A2    B   F   N
3  A3    C   G   Y
7  A4    B   F   Y
8  A5    B   F   N
9  A2    C   F   N
10 A3    B   F   Y
```

Answer (score 0):

Try 
`subset(a,Alc $in$ c("G","F"))`, which is a common way to manipulate data frame objects, along with the standard subsetting bracket function `[ ]`. Look also at the `drop` argument of `?subset`.

Comment: Actually the standard way would be probably `a[a$Alc != "E", ]`